# xpages Date Compare

Tags: datetime, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Hi i want to write Style ssjs for plan view. Set on column date variable "01.06.2007" and if document start date + duration contains 01.06.2007 result is background color change.

DateConverter.stringToDate = Java.util.date Tommy Valand code. (http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com.tr/2010/04/xpages-code-snippet-for-datestring.html)

//-------------------------------------------------
    col = 0;

```
var zeroDate = DateConverter.stringToDate( '01.06.2007', 'dd.MM.yyyy' ) 

colDate = @Adjust(zeroDate, 0, 0, col, 0, 0, 0);

duration = parseInt(rowData.getColumnValue("Duration"));

startDate = rowData.getColumnValue("Start Date");

endDate = @Adjust(startDate, 0, 0, (duration-1), 0, 0, 0);

if(startDate == colDate){
"startColor"}else if(startDate < coldate && (colDate < endDate)){
"perColor"}else{
"bgColor"}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare date values with < or > AFAIK. Transform your NotesDateTime stuff into Java date objects and use the before() and after() methods.
Like

```
var startDate:NotesDateTime = ... ;
if(startDate.toJavaDate().before(colDate.toJavaDate()) && ... ){
...
}
```

Comment: i applied this but give error  HTTP JVM: error--'Date [JavaScript Object]' t 'toJavaDate()'

Comment: If you already have a Java date you don't have to convert it with toJavaDate(). Just use the before() and after() methods then. It looked like you had NotesDateTime objects. Maybe you can show us your current code.